# python json create list

Tags: python, json, parsing

Good afternoon.
I'm getting json from a provider, but for some reason it converts the data to a list format, not a dict

Provider return json

```
def bal(number, token):
    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    }

    response = requests.get('https://api.provider.com/idS' + number, headers=headers)
    return response.json()

# parsing json
def parce_bal(jsonnn):
    f = json.dumps(jsonnn)
    f = json.loads(f)

    #for key,value in f.item():
    #    if key is 'accountNo':
    #        out_date = value
    
    out_date = type(f)
    return out_date
balance_json = balance(numberPhone, token)
f = parce_balane(balance_json)
```

`PS W:\Python\MTS> & W:/Python/P3.10/python.exe w:/Python/Mobile/main.py    <class 'list'>`

Comment: Please add `print(response.content)` immediately before `return response.json()` run your code and write what output did you get

Comment: An array (list) is a valid json object. A json object does not necessarily start with `{`. It can start with `[` as well.

Comment: Your `bal` function already returnes the JSON response loaded as python object. `parce_bal` is redundant. Why do you expect a dict? Top level of JSON response may be JSON array...

Comment: @Daweo b'[{"accountStatus":"Success","accountNo":"266385858165","customerAccountBalance":[{"type":"CustomerAccountBalance","remainedAmount":{"amount":-56396.424074},....

Comment: That looks like valid JSON array with at least one JSON object inside it... Perfectly fine. Check the API docs for what to expect

Comment: @Cycl1k this is array (note starting character: `[`), so you get list, this is how `.json()` is supposed to work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Often you can guess the kind of response you will obtain by looking at the name of the endpoint.

Here you hit the endpoint `https://api.provider.com/idS`.
With `S` at the end for plural.

In this case you're likely to expect a response with many items, returned as a JSON Array.